# How to add String arrays to a ListView

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview, fill

I've made goal_item.xml with 5 textviews.

I have Goal class, almost blank. It has ListView to be filled.

```
public class Goal extends Activity {

    ListView lvgoal;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Цели");
        setContentView(R.layout.goal);
        lvgoal= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_goal);
    }
```

goal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

       <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_goal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And I have 5 String arrays to fill the listview's textviews:

String[] name, sum, member, date, id.

How can I fill the ListView with these 5?

Comment: do not use 5 arrays of strings ... use one array of some class(TheClass) with fields: name, sum, member, date, id then use ArrayAdapter<TheClass>

Comment: Please go through a tutorial (like [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) one) on how `ListView` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement your own adapter.
Firstly create a new layout with the 5 textviews. (`example.xml`)
Then implement the adapter class.

If the 5 arrays are related, I suggest you to do the following:

```
class Data {
    public String name;
    public String sum;
    public String member;
    public String date;
    public String id;
}
```

and save your data in a unique array like that:

```
Data[] data = new Data[x];
data[0] = new Data(); //you have naturally to initialize each element :)
data[0].name = "abc";
data[0].sum = "100";
//...etc...
```

It will be simpler to create an adapter.

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, Data[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Data> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.example, null);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
        TextView t3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t3);
        TextView t4 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t4);
        TextView t5 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t5);
        Data d = getItem(position);
        t1.setText(d.name);
        t2.setText(d.sum);
        t3.setText(d.member);
        t4.setText(d.date);
        t5.setText(d.id);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Then you have to fill the listview:

```
 Data[] data;
 ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_goal);
 //...
 MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, R.layout.example,data);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Hi again. I did it like you said. I've created Data_goal class (instead of data but it's all the same with String name, String id and etc). Then I initialize it in a class like this Data_goal[] datee = new Data_goal[1];  And when I try to fill it like datee[0].name="abc"; it gives me a NullPOinterException. When I remade it for just one record datee.name='abc' it worked. Do you have any idea what it can be? and thank you very much

Comment: You have answered yourself :) I was just writing the answer! Thanks for the comment. I immediately correct my answer to prevent other to make this mistake.

Comment: And whatever..thank you for writing this code and not only writing something like "Read tutorial". I've got really tired reading pages of codes with no clue what I really need to do.

Comment: I write code because if I make a question, probably I'm encountering problems in what I'm doing (for inexperience, complexity of the problem, etc...), and probably a tutorial is not enough. I would also read the advices of a more expert person. :)

Answer (score 1):

First you must create separate XML file with your row view.

Then you should write your own adapter, where you will pass your arrays.

You can read more about it [in this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown).